# How to create a type safe factory for generic classes?

Tags: java, generics

[Note: I have looked at all the possible duplicates - none are direct duplicates and none provide an answer to this specific question.]

I want to create a factory for event handlers, where the event handler's generic type parameter is the event type. **The event type is only known at runtime**.

In code, this is an illustration of what I want to achieve:

```
public interface Event {
}

public interface EventHandler<T extends Event> {
    void handle(T event);
}

public class EventHandlerFactory {
    public <T extends Event> EventHandler<T> getHandler(Class<T> eventType) {
        return ... // implementation?
    }
}
```

And then be able to consume the events in a type safe way, like so:

```
Event event = getEvent("some json representation");
factory.getHandler(event.getClass()).handle(event);
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this (or even something similar if this is not possible)?

Edit:

A concrete event handler might look like this:

```
public class JobCreatedEventHandler implements EventHandler<JobCreatedEvent> 
{
    @Override
    public void handle(JobCreatedEvent event) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It might help to link of some of these "not helpful" existing questions.

Comment: Luckily SO does that for us in the related section. There are a few questions about creating generic factories, but TypeToInstanceMap answers don't help here.

Comment: Could you give example of concrete implementation of EventHandler?

Comment: When using factory, I would choose method name something like "create..." as factory creates new objects. Using "get..." seems like Provider/Supplier.

Comment: Curious to know - why does having "TypeToInstanceMap" not help? If you have pre-existing event handler classes, then TypeToInstanceMap actually is the solution here. If you don't have the handlers before-hand, then you can generate anonymous classes for them, with an explicit type check in the method body

Comment: Ashutosh - look at the signature of TypeToInstanceMap carefully and you will see why it doesn't help. Nor does it answer the key part of the question where types aren't known at runtime.

Comment: If the event type is not known at compile time, then it will not be possible to make this completely type-safe, because the compiler can't check the type if the type is not known at compile time.

Comment: You've said numerous times that other answers don't help, but it's still unclear why, and what you want your factory to do.

Comment: What do you exactly mean when you write "The event type is only known at runtime"? Do you mean, you have a complete fixed set of event types which is known to you and you just don't know which specific type of these fixed set of event types you get when `getEvent()` is called? Or do you mean, the complete set of possible event types that can be encountered when retrieving events via `getEvent()` is only known at runtime. In the latter case some kind of "TypeToInstanceMap" is the only way afaik.

Comment: In my opinion, the only way to handle this use case in a **completely** type-safe way is to use the visitor pattern. This implies that the set of existing concrete `EventType`s needs to be stable. Also, the factory will need to hold the reference(s) to event handlers of concrete classes as separate properties

Comment: @crizzis - I'd like to see a Visitor example - this could be what I'm looking for.

Comment: @JBNizet - solutions with TypeToInstanceMap<B> don't take into account the difference between mapping a type to its instance, and mapping a type to some other type instance. Ie, I would need TypeToInstanceMap<B, E> where E is EventHandler<B>. So one aspect is the factory, the other aspect is being able to call handle(T event) without having to cast (if possible). In summary - I am looking for the cleanest way to resolve a handler for an event, at runtime, and handle that event without having to cast the event within the EventHandler.

Comment: @Calculator - I know all the possible event types at compile time - but I don't know which one will be sent at runtime when I pass the event instance to the factory.

Answer (score 2):

A solution using the visitor pattern (as requested in the comments):

```
public interface Event {
    ...
    default void accept(EventHandlerFactory factory) {
        factory.defaultHandle(this);
    }
}

public class EventA implements Event {
    public void accept(EventHandlerFactory factory) {
        factory.handleA(this);
    }
}

public class EventB implements Event {
    public void accept(EventHandlerFactory factory) {
        factory.handleB(this);
    }
}
...

public class EventHandlerFactory {
    public void handleEvent(Event e) {
        e.accept(this);
    }

    public void handleA(EventA e) {
        this.handlerA.handle(e);
    }

    public void handleB(EventB e) {
        this.handlerB.handle(e);
    }
    ...

    public void defaultHandle(Event e) {
        LOG.error("Handler method not defined for" + e.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
}
```

Notes:

- This solution works fine if the set of event types is fixed (and thus, completely inflexible with respect to subclassing)
- You should think of organizing the classes/packages/interfaces in such a way as to reduce the visibility of `handleA`, `handleB` etc. to the actual client classes of `EventFactory`
- The default `Event.accept` method is not strictly required; in your use case, I don't think there's a sensible implementation of `EventHandlerFactory.defaultHandle`
- Of course, you could make the `Event.handle` methods to return the call to an appropriate getter method, e.g. `return factory.getEventHandlerForB`, if you require that type of indirection

This solution is entirely inflexible (pretty much because the visitor pattern is about the least flexible pattern ever invented), but it gets the job done. Note that no single casting/lookup by class is required.

Comment: Nice, thanks. This is definitely a possibility, though I was hoping not to have to create `public void handleA(EventA e)` style methods for extensibility purposes. Ideally I'd like a solution that can be wired up using a DI container, rather than having to add new methods for each new event type. But still, a nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

There rests only

1. an unsafe map being made safe at runtime, and
2. the same for handling an event in principle generically.

The unavoidable matter is to hold a map not on `Class<T>` to `EventHandler<T>` but on the less type-safe `Class<? extends Event>` - one cannot map with pairwise type-safeness.

```
nterface Event {
}

interface EventHandler<T extends Event> {
    void handle(T event);
    default void handleGen(Event event) {
        handle((T)event);
    }
}

class A implements Event {
}

class B implements Event {
}

class AHandler implements EventHandler<A> {

    @Override
    public void handle(A event) {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

class BHandler implements EventHandler<B> {

    @Override
    public void handle(B event) {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
```

The factory class:

```
// No type equality required between key and value handler's parameter.
private Map<Class<? extends Event>, EventHandler<? extends Event>> map = new HashMap<>();

public <T extends Event> void registerHandler(Class<T> eventType,
            EventHandler<T> handler) {
    map.put(eventType, handler);
}

public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    Class<? extends Event> eventType = event.getClass();
    EventHandler<? extends Event> handler = map.get(eventType);
    if (handler != null) {
        handler.handleGen(eventType.cast(event));
    }
}
```

Type-safe usage:

```
    registerHandler(A.class, new AHandler());
    registerHandler(B.class, new BHandler());
    A a = new A();
    handleEvent(a);
```

The solution is in the handleGen:

```
        handler.handleGen(eventType.cast(event));
```

The abstract base class can hold a package private *generic* method `handleGen`
 that delegates to the real handle method. Because of the register method this is safe at run-time.

Comment: There is one caveat: this solution won't work if `EventType` is proxied at runtime. I suppose there is little point in proxying an event, but I've seen this happen once or twice in similar map-based solutions. To be on the safe side, if a handler is not found, the search should be repeated with superclasses until the inheritance hierarchy is exhausted or a match is found.

Comment: I also once had to climb up the class hierarchy in order to find a handler. Here, based on interfaces, one has to check all the interfaces implemented. Could be gruesome.

Answer (score 0):

At some point, some part of the logic needs to recognise that objects of class `A` are handled by objects of class `B` and objects of class `B` need to have a method (for the sake of argument) called `handleEvent()` which (probably) appears in a common `interface` called (say) `EventHandler`.

Whether you implement a type-to-instance map or just hack:

```
Class<?> c=Class.forName(event.getClass().getName()+"Handler");
```

Or a long chain of `if``else` statements or something similar. 
Some kind of mapping must take place.

I don't see a way around that.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for something like this.

```
public class EventHandlerFactory {
    private HashMap<Class, EventHandler> map = new HashMap<>();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T extends Event> EventHandler<T> getHandler(Class<? extends T> eventType) {
        return (EventHandler<T>) map.get(eventType);
    }

    public <T extends Event> setHandler(Class<? extends T> eventType, EventHandler<T> handler) {
        map.put(eventType, handler);
    }
}
```

Type safety cannot be enforced by the map, so instead it is enforced by the setter method. An event type can only be mapped to a handler for that class or one of its superclasses.

Comment: Ok thanks, but how would you handle the interesting part of handling a command once you have retrieved a handler from the map?